# Subset dataframe with dynamic conditions using various number of columns as arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 7)), columns=list('ABCDEFG'))
```

that I need to pull a subset of `df` based on a series of conditions on selected columns but the columns are to be tuned. With said, the conditions are 'dynamic' that give various subsets, such as (to make the scenario easy, let's use all `&`):

```python
dfs = df[(df.A > 10) & (df.C > 5) & (df.E < 30)]
dfs = df[(df.C > 5) & (df.D < 0)]
dfs = df[(df.B > 20) & (df.E < 30) & (df.F > 7) & (df.G < 15)]
...
```

Question is, is it possible to write a function that takes the columns and their compared values as some kind of `**kwargs` that returns different subset with different column list? Many thanks!

Please note sub-setting is not the main issue here. It's how we pass different combinations of different columns and their corresponding compared values as arguments.

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165056/6692898, but maybe include some pseudocode of your expected function

Comment: @RichieV thanks for the link. sub-setting is not the main issue here. but how do we pass different combinations of different columns and compared values within the queries as arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to pass a tuple containing the comparator and the target value, as such:

```
>>> def apply_filters(df, **kwargs):
...   for col in kwargs.keys():
...     df = df.loc[kwargs[col][0](df[col], kwargs[col][1])]
...   return df

>>> apply_filters(df, A=(pd.Series.__lt__, 10), C=(pd.Series.__lt__, 10))
    A   B  C   D   E   F   G
52  0  22  2  35  81  56  10
54  2  83  5   7  91  38  79
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do something along those lines

```
def foo(df, *args):
    r=True
    for (i,arg) in enumerate(args):
        r = r & df[arg[0]].isin(arg[1])
    return df[r]
```

example:

```
foo(df, ['A',[51,83]],['B',[38,89]],['C',[45,27]])
```

will yield (for my random values)

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0  51  38  45  80  64   7  17
1  51  89  27  86  22  82  70
```

you can improve foo with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961337/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-dictionary-with-various-functions/52968585) reference

Comment: It's not 100% what I expect but thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

May just do  `query`

```
def jsutstring(df, x, y, z):
        return df.query(' and '.join(s + v + str(t) for t, s, v in zip(x, y, z)))
    
out = jsutstring(df, [10,10], ['A','C'], ['>', '>'])
```

Comment: Interesting way to use `query`. Good to learn. Wish I could accept both answers but thanks for the elegant solution!